# UI Implementation, best route to take

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, user-controls

I'm working on a small application that I need some assistance with implementing.

The gist is I would like to create a grid-like container that houses a dynamic number of the identical column-like structures. Inside each column-like structure is a few text fields and radio buttons that the user can interact with.

I've been looking into some different WPF objects that may be of some help, but I'm pretty overwhelmed.

Some things I've thought of:

- The column-like structure can be a custom built UserControl. This UserControl will have all the logic to deal with the interactions of the various buttons and text fields.
- We can use a StackPanel, set to Horizontal, to house these UserControls. From what I've gathered, a StackPanel seems like it may be the perfect container for my purpose.

Some questions I have:

- Will I need to create a .xaml for the UserControl?
- In the event that more UserControls that can be displayed are added, does the StackPanel provide a way to scroll from left to right with a horizontal scroll bar?
- Do I need to custom define the size of UserControl, or is it possible to just specify a set width and use the height of the StackPanel?
- Is there an easier or more appropriate solution?

Lastly, I've included a very rough sketch to provide a visual idea of what I'm looking to do:

[image: very rough sketch]

Comment: 1. "Will I need to create a .xaml for the UserControl?" Yes, a UserControl consists of XAML and a code. 2. Put the UserControl in the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl. This way its DataContext is bound to the appropriate data item of an item collection that the ItemsControl's ItemsSource property is bound to. 3. Use a horizontal StackPanel for the ItemsControl's ItemsPanel. 4. Put the ItemsControl in a ScrollViewer.

Comment: @Clemens If it's not too much to ask, could you give me an example of what the XAML would look like for the ItemsControl?

Comment: You may want to start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your questions:

1. You shall definitely extract a control for each part of your control which is used more than once.

[image]

2. A stack panel is a container, is similar to a `div` in HTML. If you want to show a scroll, you better use `ScrollViewer` instead of `Stackpanel`.
3. If the height of the StackPanel/ScrollViewer is set, controls inside them, will respect that limit unless you actually set an explicit height for the child elements. If the height of the Stackpanel/ScrollViewer is not set, the children elements will be stretched (so, in order to fit into the parent, you have to specify a height). You can decide, however, how you want to do it.
4. I think that is a god solution to extract a control for each redundant part and use a ScrollViewer!

If something is unclear, please let me know! Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by reading a bit about the MVVM pattern which plays well with WPF. Other than that I would use a ListView instead of a horizontal stackpanel and a scrollviewer. I Would prefer my data to expand vertically than horizontally. Here's some sample code to use.

Here's your model class:

```
public enum CustomOption
{
    Option1,
    Option2,
    Option3
}

public class Item
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }

    public string Value2 { get; set; }

    public string Value3 { get; set; }

    CustomOption Option { get; set; }
}
```

Here's your ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And here's your MainWindow:

```
<ScrollViewer
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="EnumValues" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
                <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                    <x:Type TypeName="local:CustomOption"/>
                </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            </ObjectDataProvider>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Value1" Margin="5"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value1}" Margin="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Value2" Margin="5"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value2}" Margin="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Value3" Margin="5"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value3}" Margin="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Option" Margin="5"/>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source ={StaticResource EnumValues}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Option}" Margin="5"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This is a very simplistic example to get you started. You can play around to get a much better looking style and layout. I used a ComboBox instead of RadioButtons which I dislike. You also need to set the DataContext of your MainWindow as the MainWindowVM somewhere. You can do that when your application starts for now.